# Compare What User Typed in VF inputText with JavaScript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, actionfunction, inputtext

In the code below, I need to be able to use JS to call `renderResults();` in my controller, only if a user clears the field where `customerToClearSearchText` goes on the VF page.

If I remove the condition, the method successfully executes; so I know that's where the problem is.

```
<apex:outputpanel >
    <apex:inputText id="customerToClearSearchText" value="{!customerToClearSearchText}" rendered="{!customerToClearInputRendered}" onkeydown="showResults()"/>
    <apex:actionFunction name="CallApexMethod" action="{!renderResults}"/>
    <script>                    
        function showResults(){
            var st = document.getElementById("customerToClearSearchText").value;
            if(st.length == 0){
                CallApexMethod();
            }
        }    
    </script>                
</apex:outputpanel>
```

To no avail I also tried:

- `document.getElementById("customerToClearSearchText")`
- `if(!st)`
- `if(!!st)`

My guess is it doesn't work because the condition is evaluating the (now) populated string - `customerToClearSearchText` - in the controller; not the length of anything the user is (now) putting into the field on the page.

At any rate, is there anyway to do what I'm trying to accomplish?  BTW, *I'm completely new to JS*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in assuming that the ID you specify on the input element is the same that will be rendered in the page. Unfortunately, that's not how Visualforce works; it prepends the ID with additional characters to make it unique. The typical way to resolve this is to use a partial-match selector or even a different attribute altogether. The following should work:

```
var st = document.querySelector("[id$=customerToClearSearchText]").value;
if(!st) {
  CallApexMethod();
}
```

---

Edit: As an alternative, you can pass in "this" to link to the element:

```
<apex:inputText id="customerToClearSearchText" value="{!customerToClearSearchText}" rendered="{!customerToClearInputRendered}" onkeydown="showResults(this)"/>
```

...

```
function showResults(el){
    var st = el.value;
    if(!st) {
        CallApexMethod();
    }
}
```

---

In JavaScript, onkeydown occurs before the input's value changes; use onkeyup instead.

Comment: Oh, good to know!  However, oddly, now typing anything in fires the code.

Comment: @GabrielRivera On key down is the wrong event to respond to, by the way; the state of the input hasn't been updated yet. Try "onchange" instead.

Comment: I changed the attribute to onchange, but still no luck.  It once again seems to me that looking at the inputText value has something to do with it.  When I inspect the field after clearing it, it seems to indicate that the actual value hasn't' changed.  When I refresh the page after clearing the field, the field repopulates with the original value.

Comment: @GabrielRivera That's the "view state" in action. It is working, because the view state is being updated. I'm not sure that you're asking the right questions at this point; your code is overly complicated when it doesn't need to be.

Comment: I experimented further and saw that your solution does work, but only when I click anywhere else after clearing the field.  I was hoping the code would fire just by clearing the field.

Comment: @GabrielRivera Try "onkeyup" instead, then.